# Kafka consumer test and reported metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

I want to understand how kafka consumer test works and how to interpret some of numbers reported,

below is the test i ran and the output i got. My questions are

1. values reported for `rebalance.time.ms, fetch.time.ms, fetch.MB.sec, fetch.nMsg.sec` are `1593109326098, -1593108732333, -0.0003, -0.2800`; can you explain how it can report such a high and negative numbers ? they dont make sense to me.
2. Everything reported from  `Metric Name       Value` line is reported due to `--print-metrics` flag. What is difference between metrics reported by default and with this flag? how they are calculated and where can i read about what do they mean?
3. No matter i scale total consumer running in parallel or scale network and io threads at broker, `consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-latency-avg` metrics remains almost same. can you explain this? with more consumers pulling data fetch latency should go higher; similarly for given consuming rate if i reduce io and network thread parameters at broker shouldnt latency scale higher?

here is the command i ran

```
[root@oak-clx17 kafka_2.12-2.5.0]# bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --topic topic_test8_cons_test1 --threads 1  --broker-list clx20:9092 --messages 500000000 --consumer.config config/consumer.properties --print-metrics
```

and results

```
    start.time, end.time, data.consumed.in.MB, MB.sec, data.consumed.in.nMsg, nMsg.sec, rebalance.time.ms,fetch.time.ms, fetch.MB.sec, fetch.nMsg.sec
    WARNING: Exiting before consuming the expected number of messages: timeout (10000 ms) exceeded. You can use the --timeout option to increase the timeout.
    2020-06-25 11:22:05:814, 2020-06-25 11:31:59:579, 435640.7686, 733.6922, 446096147, 751300.8463, 1593109326098, -1593108732333, -0.0003, -0.2800
     
    Metric Name                                                                                                                                    Value
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:assigned-partitions:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                  : 0.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:commit-latency-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                   : 2.700
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:commit-latency-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                   : 4.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:commit-rate:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                          : 0.230
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:commit-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                         : 119.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:failed-rebalance-rate-per-hour:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                       : 0.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:failed-rebalance-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                               : 1.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:heartbeat-rate:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                       : 0.337
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:heartbeat-response-time-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                          : 6.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:heartbeat-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                      : 197.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:join-rate:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                            : 0.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:join-time-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                        : NaN
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:join-time-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                        : NaN
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:join-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                           : 1.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:last-heartbeat-seconds-ago:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                           : 2.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:last-rebalance-seconds-ago:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                           : 593.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:partition-assigned-latency-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                       : NaN
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:partition-assigned-latency-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                       : NaN
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:partition-lost-latency-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                           : NaN
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:partition-lost-latency-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                           : NaN
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:partition-revoked-latency-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                        : 0.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:partition-revoked-latency-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                        : 0.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:rebalance-latency-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                : NaN
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:rebalance-latency-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                : NaN
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:rebalance-latency-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                              : 83.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:rebalance-rate-per-hour:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                              : 0.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:rebalance-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                      : 1.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:sync-rate:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                            : 0.000
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:sync-time-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                        : NaN
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:sync-time-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                        : NaN
    consumer-coordinator-metrics:sync-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                           : 1.000
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:bytes-consumed-rate:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1, topic=topic_test8_cons_test1}                  : 434828205.989
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:bytes-consumed-rate:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                : 434828205.989
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:bytes-consumed-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1, topic=topic_test8_cons_test1}                 : 460817319851.000
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:bytes-consumed-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                               : 460817319851.000
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-latency-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                  : 58.870
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-latency-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                  : 503.000
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-rate:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                         : 48.670
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-size-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1, topic=topic_test8_cons_test1}                       : 9543108.526
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-size-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                     : 9543108.526
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-size-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1, topic=topic_test8_cons_test1}                       : 11412584.000
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-size-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                     : 11412584.000
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-throttle-time-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                            : 0.000
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-throttle-time-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                            : 0.000
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-25533-1}                                                        : 44889.000
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4426)
            at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2951)
            at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2898)
            at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2673)
            at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2609)
            at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2897)
            at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.format(StringLike.scala:354)
            at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.format$(StringLike.scala:353)
            at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.format(StringOps.scala:33)
            at kafka.utils.ToolsUtils$.$anonfun$printMetrics$3(ToolsUtils.scala:60)
            at kafka.utils.ToolsUtils$.$anonfun$printMetrics$3$adapted(ToolsUtils.scala:58)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
            at kafka.utils.ToolsUtils$.printMetrics(ToolsUtils.scala:58)
            at kafka.tools.ConsumerPerformance$.main(ConsumerPerformance.scala:82)
            at kafka.tools.ConsumerPerformance.main(ConsumerPerformance.scala)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. https://medium.com/metrosystemsro/apache-kafka-how-to-test-performance-for-clients-configured-with-ssl-encryption-3356d3a0d52b it's a post I've written on this.

Expectation according to [this KIP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-177%3A+Consumer+perf+tool+should+count+rebalance+time) is for *rebalance.time.ms* and *fetch.time.ms* to show total rebalance time for the consumer group and the total fetching time excluding the rebalance time.
As far I can tell, as of Apache Kafka version 2.6.0 this is still a work in progress and currently the output are timestamps in [Unix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
*fetch.MB.sec* and *fetch.nMsg.sec* are intended to show the average quantity of messages consumed per second (in MB and as a count)

2. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumer_group_monitoring for the consumer group metrics listed with *--print-metrics* flag
3. *fetch-latency-avg* (the average time taken for a fetch request) will vary but this depends a lot on the test setup.